# angular js $http return true or false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, return, promise

I have the following code in a service in angular:

```
this.login = function(email, password)
{

    var promise =  $http({
        url: 'user/authenticate',
        method: "POST",
        data: { 'email' : email, 'password' : password }
    });

    promise.then(
      function(payload) {
         return true;
        }
      );
}
```

Here is my calling code:

```
var loginResult = loginService.login(data.email, data.password);
        alert(oginResult);
        if (loginResult)
        {
            $modalInstance.close("");
            $state.go("home");
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.error = "Login not found.";
        }
```

Im trying to get true to return to the calling service.login.  However all I get back is undefined.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the code. Return promise from service and do your work in **.then** in controller.

Service

```
this.login = function(email, password)
{

    var promise =  $http({
        url: 'user/authenticate',
        method: "POST",
        data: { 'email' : email, 'password' : password }
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Controller

```
loginService.login(data.email, data.password).then(function(loginResult){
        alert(loginResult);
        if (loginResult)
        {
            $modalInstance.close("");
            $state.go("home");
        }
        else
        {
            $scope.error = "Login not found.";
        }


});
```

Comment: Ok, I was hoping to fulfill the promise in the service and then return true or false that way my code outside the service could look neat.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create a promise into your SErvice

   ```
   this.login = function(email, password)
   {
     // we directly return $http as $http is a promise.
     return  $http({
         url: 'user/authenticate',
         method: "POST",
         data: { 'email' : email, 'password' : password }
     });
   }
   ```
2. Manage promise response into your controller

   ```
      // manage the promise return with .then(function() and the response with the parameter of the function

   loginService.login(data.email, data.password).then(function(loginResult){

       if (loginResult)
       {
           $modalInstance.close("");
           $state.go("home");
       }
       else
       {
           $scope.error = "Login not found.";
       }


   });
   ```